# Load modal content from JSON with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way that I can load a Modal with data from a JSON response?

For example,

here's a link to sign out of my application:

```
 <a tabindex="-1" href="/ajax/account/logout" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ajax" class="modal-link">Sign Out</a>
```

In a normal circumstance, the response will be:

```
 {"html":"htmlsource",
  "resultCode":1}
```

The html contains the HTML of the content to be put into the modal, so all I'd need to do is extract the html data and push it to the div container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this:

```
$.getJSON(url).success(function(data) {
   $('#ajax, div').replaceWith(data.html);
   $('#ajax').modal();
});
```

Comment: I was thinking that, but how would I structure it? I mean, given that it's affecting the default modal system already in TB?

Comment: You can also add a dummy inner div in the modl body and use replaceWith(data.html)

Comment: How would I capture the event that the ajax call is made? I mean, I could use `$('#ajax').on('show', function ()` ?

Comment: I thought it was the other way around: the ajax call triggering the modal content and showing it.

Comment: Basically, a user clicks on a link, which does an ajax call. The data is returned to the modal.

Comment: Remove the data-toggle, data-target from the link, add a click event which does the ajax call. The ajax callback loads and shows the modal (as in the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Sure; for example, the `html()` jQuery function will shove its argument into whatever element you wish, including a Modal.  In your case, assuming the "html" item has what you want to put in the Modal, you'd do something like `$("#id-of-modal").html(response.html)`.

Comment: I've edited the question - was still typing when you responded :)